# apt-get update fails with "403 Forbidden: Category denied"

Tags: apt, updates

When executing `apt-get update` on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, I receive the following message:

```
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden: category denied [IP: 141.30.62.26 80]
```

And I am unable to install any new packages.

I am on an x86_64 system. What causes this error and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Try using a different mirror.  THat one might be temporarily busted.  Also, you don't happen to have a proxy somewhere that you are using, do you?  Category Denied in the 403 error is not a standard error message...

Comment: I tried a different mirror already, to no avail.
I don't have a proxy configured - at least by intention. I need to query my network admin if a transparent proxy is in use.

Comment: can you please use code markup, the `{}`on top of the editor and post the whole output ? Is the error only when installing or `sudo apt-get update` work ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the Proxy, @ThomasWard - this was it: The network admin affirmed the existance of a transparent proxy. By bypassing it, the problem vanished!

Answer (score 0):

A transparent network proxy with a dedicated ruleset prevented downloading of data from the repository servers.
Once the rules have been deleted, `apt-get update` worked fine.
Since the proxy is a transparent one, it is not configured anywhere on the server.